# how to get a Integer value from a Combo box in java?

Tags: java

I've created a class named as **fontlist** and I want to get the Integer value from the Combo box, but it gives me some error.

How do I get an Integer value from the Combo box?  Also, I want to change the size of text according to an integer value that gets to the fontsize Combo Box ...

My code is:

```
        import java.awt.*;
        import javax.swing.*;
        import java.awt.event.*;
        import java.util.*;

        class fontlist extends JFrame implements ItemListener
        { JComboBox jcb,fontSize;
        Container content;
        JTextArea jta;
        JScrollPane jsp;
        private static final int[] fontsize = {8,9,10,11,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,36,48,72};

        fontlist()
        {
        content=getContentPane();
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        jcb=new JComboBox();
        content.add(jcb);
        jcb.setBounds(100,100,100,20);

        fontSize=new JComboBox();
        content.add(fontSize);
        fontSize.setBounds(200,100,100,20);
        jta=new JTextArea();
        jsp=new JScrollPane(jta);
        content.add(jsp);
        jsp.setBounds(100,120,200,200);
        jcb.addItemListener(this);
        fontSize.addItemListener(this);
        String fonts[] = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
        for ( int i = 0; i < fonts.length; i++ )
        {
        jcb.addItem(fonts[i]);
        } 
        for ( int j = 0; j <16; j++ )
        {
        fontSize.addItem(fontsize[j]);
        } 
        }
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie)
        {
        if (ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) 
        {
        System.out.println(""+fontSize.getSelectedItem());
          String size = (fontSize.getSelectedItem()+"");
         System.out.println(size);
         int size1 =Integer(size);
        }
        }
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
        fontlist fl=new fontlist();
        fl.setSize(700,500);
        fl.setVisible(true);
        }

        }
```

And the error is:

[image]

Comment: use an IDE to check your syntax

Comment: Use an IDE for everything, IDEs are awesome </religious zeal>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to use:

```
int size1 = new Integer( size );
```

Or you could use:

```
int size1 = Integer.parseInt( size );
```

(Both will require you to use a try/catch block to catch `NumberFormatException`)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
int size1 =Integer(size);
```

to

```
int size1 = Integer.parseInt(size);
```

**After a second look at your code**

```
int size1 = (Integer)(fontSize.getSelectedItem());
```

may also work.

Comment: size is a string, you cannot cast it to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

declare `fontSize` as `JComboBox<Integer> fontSize`

you need to let java know that the combo box hold Integers
If you look at the documentation for [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) , you will note it is declared as `JComboBox<E>`. The `E` is what is know as a type parameter and describes what type of data the JComboBox will hold. If you don't iunclude it, it will default to `Object`

Comment: You don't have to, but if you don't do this, you'll have to cast.

Comment: @lordoku but you would be defeating the whole purpose of the Generics mechanism

Comment: you're right. I'm just saying there's no hard requirement to. It's definitely best practices to do the generics mechanism. Also it doesn't matter, because even if you supply the generic type, the getSelectedItem's return type is still an Object. Although I suppose the prefered way now is to do JComboBox.getItemAt(JComboBox.getSelectedIndex) and that will return the generic type.